# Using PDO prepared statement and a placeholder for a specific year, I can't echo any results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I've recently learned the importance of prepared statements so I'm embarking on changing all my existing mysqli queries to PDO queries.

I have a table called "people" with fields called `name` and `dob` (DATETIME), which have data like:

```
name:  Johnny
dob:  2016-12-06 18:30:00
```

I supply a year in a PHP variable first, for example:

```
$theyear=2016;
```

Then, using this example, I'm trying to pull all names for people with a dob in 2016 and echo them, like this below, but it's not displaying any results (and there are plenty):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE `dob` BETWEEN ':theyear-01-01' AND ':theyear-12-31'");
$stmt->execute(['theyear' => $theyear]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['name'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Being new to PDO, I'm sure I did something stupid/illogical.

Can anybody see my mistake/help me get in the right direction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql a dupe of, technically

Comment: and your query doesn't make sense though. You need to use different names if emulation is not set

Comment: you need to set your variables' values *before* querying, then pass those on in the query *after*, this in a nutshell. Quite a few ways to do this actually.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - you're not checking for errors at all. What you posted would have thrown you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to concatenate, do it in the array, not the query and use separate placeholders for each variable:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE `dob` BETWEEN :theyearbegin AND :theyearend");
$stmt->execute([':theyearbegin' => $theyear.'-01-01', ':theyearend' => $theyear.'-12-31']);
```

Note that I have removed the quotes from the placeholders in the query. Any concatenation you do to be held in a placeholder for a prepared query should be done outside of the query itself, including queries where you use `LIKE`.

Comment: The CONCAT way @MVG1984 mentioned worked, but it sounds like I shouldn't do that in the query itself, so I want your way to work but it's not for some reason.  No errors, just echo's nothing.  Maybe I had a typo or something, but I copied it straight from here so a little perplexed.  Ill keep toying tho, thanks!

Comment: Found it.  Yours was missing a hyphen before "12-31".  Added it and it works now, thanks again for your knowledge!

Comment: Quick follow up if you'll indulge me...  I see you have colons in the keys.  I read that they are unnecessary.  Do you feel they SHOULD be used for a specific reason?

Comment: Thanks @user3304303! I was staring at it and just didn't see it. Glad to have helped!

Comment: I just keep the colons for a sanity check, they are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change

```
':theyear-01-01'
```

To

```
CONCAT(:theyear, '-01-01')
```

And if emulation is not set, you need two different variables, :theyear1 and :theyear2 f.e.

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: This way worked, but I'll have to read up about emulation to decide if that should be set or not, thank you